# Elasticsearch search Template - How do you preregister with conditional clauses?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am checking the conditional clause templates mentioned here 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html#_conditional_clauses
and based on it I am trying to convert the below query to conditional based template

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": { 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "search_string": {
                "query": "{{search}}",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}

The above script I stored in my_template.mustache and ran with the below command . This went well

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' http://localhost:9200/_scripts/my_template_search -d @./my_template.mustache
```

Now I am trying the same above query for conditional based search and so I added `search` condition to it using `{{#search}}` and `{{/search}}`

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": { 
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          {{#search}}
          "must": {
            "match": {
              "search_string": {
                "query": "{{search}}",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
          {{/search}}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I run this file using the same above **CURL** command I am getting JSON exception .

I also tried 
1) Escaping the query
2) and also passing directly the query in CURL command using the below but no luck

Can any body help me what is wrong in this ?  Thanks for your help.

I also checked https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-do-you-preregister-a-search-template-with-conditional-clauses/135768 , but unfortunately that didn't help me

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_scripts/my_template_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d  '{"script":{"lang":"mustache","source":"{\"query\":{\"bool\":{{{#stch\":{\"search_string\":{\"query\":\"{{search}}\",\"operator\":\"and\"}}}{{/search}}}}}"}}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass valid json to elasticsearch, so the `source` parameter must be a string if it is not valid json. To build the string you must escape the query.

You also need to add whitespaces (or any other separator) when you have `{{{` to avoid mustache errors. This is related to [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/32527).

In your case replace `{{{#search}}` by `{ {{#search}}`

The following query should work :

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{ {{#search}}\"must\":[{\"match\":{\"search_string\":{\"query\":\"{{search}}\",\"operator\":\"and\"}}}]{{\/search}}}}}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this worked just perfect . Thanks a lot for your response and helping me to resolve my issue . I spend two days to debug this (  But I missed the link you gave me ) . For the big templates escaping the characters is a big pain . Is there any easy way ? like 1) Importing directly template from the file 2) auto escaping the query part ..?  Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad it helped ! I don't think there is any way without escaping the search query.